# Python: If x is equal to a, b, c, or d?

Tags: python, if-statement

In Python, is it possible to test a variable against multiple values, i.e. a shorter way of writing:

```
if (x=="a") or (x=="b") or (x=="c") ...
```

like maybe: `if x=="a" or "b" or "c":`?

Comment: You don't need the ().

Comment: Probably [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/1399279) is a better duplicate...

Comment: I have seen that question, and it is slightly different. It is asking if one of a set of variables is equal to a given value, not whether a single variable is equal one of a set of values, which is my query.